# Google Maps API NativeScript custom marker icon

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, nativescript

I try to create a marker with a custom icon with NativeScript and the Google maps API package. I added my icon to the android resources and then built my project a few times.

```
   var marker = new mapsModule.Marker();
   marker.position = mapsModule.Position.positionFromLatLng(result.latitude, result.longitude);
   marker.title = "Home";
   var icon = new Image();
   icon.imageSource = imageSource.fromResource('bot_marker');
   marker.icon = icon;
   marker.snippet = "This is where I live";
   marker.userData = { index: 1 };
   mapView.addMarker(marker);
```

Even when I try `icon` or `logo` for the ressource it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Angular2

```
import { Image } from "ui/image";
import { ImageSource } from "image-source";

    onMapReady(event) {
        console.log("Google map is ready!");

        var mapView = event.object;
        var marker = new Marker();
        marker.position = Position.positionFromLatLng(this.state.latitude, this.state.longitude);

        let imgSrc = new ImageSource();
        imgSrc.fromResource("pink_pin_dot");

        let image = new Image();
        image.imageSource = imgSrc;

        marker.icon = image;
        mapView.addMarker(marker);
    }
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to implement it on nativescript-vue?

Comment: @Danno In my case, I'm having a URL for icon. And Icons are not getting rendered on map. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Using Vue this worked for me.

**Note 1:** `fromResource` and `fromFile` have been deprecated and new functions are called `fromFileSync` and `fromResourceSync`

**Note 2**: Do not change marker color after setting the icon, this will show you the default icon although you would have set ImageSource for custom icon correctly

1 ) import required NativeScript libraries

```
import { Image } from "ui/image";
import { ImageSource } from "image-source";
import { Marker } from "nativescript-google-maps-sdk";
```

2 a) Add custom marker image using local path

```
 const marker = new Marker()
 const imageSource = ImageSource.fromFileSync( "~/assets/images/icons/icon.png");
 const icon = new Image();
 icon.imageSource = imageSource;
 marker.icon = icon;
```

OR

2 b) Add custom marker image using resources (in Android for example these live in drawable folders in `app/App_Resources/Android/src/main/res`, here the example image is `icon.png`)

```
 const marker = new Marker()
 const imageSource = ImageSource.fromResourceSync("icon");
 const icon = new Image();
 icon.imageSource = imageSource;
 marker.icon = icon;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Nativescript version 6 i used the following code to make it work with local image file.

```
import {ImageSource} from "tns-core-modules/image-source";
import { Image } from "tns-core-modules/ui/image";
import {Folder, path, knownFolders} from "tns-core-modules/file-system"; 

/** Then in the point of adding the marker **/
const folder: Folder = <Folder>knownFolders.currentApp();
const folderPath: string = path.join(folder.path, "images/marker-blue.png");
const imageFromLocalFile: ImageSource = ImageSource.fromFileSync(folderPath);
let image = new Image();
image.imageSource = imageFromLocalFile;
marker.icon = image;
```