# custom icon from url, not from assets - nativescript google maps ios

Tags: ios, google-maps-markers, nativescript-angular

I try a lot but not success to find a way to show icon of marker from url.

```
 addMarker(mark, index): void {
    const marker = new Marker();
    marker.position = Position.positionFromLatLng(mark.latitude, mark.longitude);
    marker.icon = 'iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/map-marker-2-xxl.png'; // default pin
    this.mapView.addMarker(marker);
 }
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814384/google-maps-api-nativescript-custom-marker-icon) for icons image from assets was working fine. now I have icons stored on cloud and I need to use them as per record.

Answer (score 1):

Since loading image from assets works with an ImageSource, I believe you should be able to do a similar thing for images from URL. Also see [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource#fromurl)

The ImageSource has a 'fromUrl' you can call. So this should work for you (borrowing part of the code from your linked question)

```
 let imgSrc = new ImageSource();
 imgSrc.fromUrl("iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/map-marker-2-xxl.png");

 let image = new Image();
 image.imageSource = imgSrc;

 marker.icon = image;
```

You should probably [cache](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/image-cache) the image so it won't be downloaded x times.